# Gradle sync error with android.productFlavors setting

Tags: android-ndk, gradle-experimental

I use com.android.tools.build:cradle-experimental:0.7.0.
And want to build only for some abi.
So I set android.productFlavors as below:

```
productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
    }
```

I got sync error:Error:Unable to find Android binary with buildType 'debug' and productFlavor '' in project ':xduilib'

I had google for this error message, but no result.

It is ok to only set one platform. why?  What's wrong with my setting or product.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use this to set target platform.

```
android.ndk {
        moduleName = 'xxx'
        abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64']) //this is default
        ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
    }
```